# cfscript Code Assist in CFBuilder

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion

I'm increasingly using cfscript, and like it where appropriately used.

One problem is that there doesn't appear to be any code assist for cfscript in CF Builder, so I find myself writing the tag of a function to leverage the code Assist, then converting to cfscript (which is silly).

For example:
`addParam()` is the cfscript equivalent of `<cfqueryparam >`.  I get code assist when writing the the tag version, but not the script equivalent.

Does anyone know if there is a code assist library available for cfscript in cfBuilder?  Or is this just a downside of working with cfscript?

Many Thanks in advance!

Jason

Comment: file a new feature request: https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not using native CFScript, it's using the hack-solution Adobe provided for some shortcomings of CFScript's coverage of CF tags, which are implemented as a bunch of CFCs in the custom tags dir of your install.  This stuff is not representative of CFML & its CFScript support as a whole.

I find that CFB gives hinting for most *native* functionality... is this not the case for you? What if you try listAppend() for example?  Do you get code-assist for that?

UPDATE

I wonder if you get a warning in CFB on your line equivalent to this:

```
o = new Query();
```

?  I do, by default.  I have to make a link to the CustomTags/com dir, and then use this syntax:

```
o = new com.adobe.Query();
```

Then I don't get a warning, and indeed I get the code assist you're expecting.  I cannot get it to give me hinting on just the non-qualified path to Query.cfc though.

Not ideal.  Or maybe I'm missing something, too.

Comment: Thanks Adam, good points re: native - non native, but how the functions are implemented are irrelevant to whether there is code hinting for them or not.  (I have code hinting for cfWheels functions, which are not native). From what you are saying, would the answer be that there is code hinting for native script functions, but no code hinting for non-native functions (thus a downside of using cfscript)?  Thanks again Adam.

Comment: Oh sure, I wasn't suggesting it *shouldn't* work for you, I was just wanting to clarify whether it was just on those methods, or across-the-board.  Those CFCs are a bit of a non-standard case, after all.

Comment: Thanks Adam..   I think you could have something.. I don't get warning when using ..new Query(); ,but do get a warning with new com.adobe.Query(); warning is 'unresolved component com.adobe.Query();'  Maybe my install of cfBuilder isn't mapping to the cfc's properly, but I couldn't find anywhere in preferences that this would be set..  I'll keep poking around and see what I can find..